# How do you solve the Praat error 'Wrong xmin and xmax" whentrying to open an export from ELAN?

Tags: import, export, praat

I am working with a transcription created in ELAN and I want to export it to Praat.

In ELAN, I have selected: Export As: Praat TextGrid and left the settings as they are (see screenshot) [image: Screenshot of ELAN export settings]

Then I have saved it with UTF-8 encoding (using UTF-16 encoding makes no difference).

When I open Praat and select the file using 'Read from file' it comes up with the following error (see screenshot)

[image: Praat error message]

Wrong xmin 3633.202 and xmax 3003.288
IntervalTier not read.
TextGrid not read.
Data not read from text file....

I have tried saving the file as UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding and Praat gave the same error.
I tried exporting only one tier - same issue.
I tried selecting a small part of the data and only exporting this and that worked, but I need the whole sample. Manually selecting the whole data and exporting using 'restricted selected time interval' also gave the same error in Praat.

I don't know what xmin or xmax is or how I could edit them to align it with what Praat needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was actually to do with a misalignment in ELAN
I managed to solve it in ELAN by finding the misaligned part under 'errors' and then manually adjusting the problematic tiers. There were intervals that were overlapping on the same tier for some strange reason.